# Replace vector elements with indexes from list of positions

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a vector of values:

```
y=c(2,3,4,4,3,2,1,1)
```

And a list of vectors of positions:

```
l=list(c(1,2),c(2,3),c(3,4),c(4,5),c(5,6),c(6,7),c(7,8),c(8,1))
```

I'd like to replace the value of `y` by NAs (or other) for each of the element in the list `l`.

Expected output is a list of length `length(l)`:

```r
[[1]]
[1] NA NA  4  4  3  2  1  1

[[2]]
[1]  2 NA NA  4  3  2  1  1

[[3]]
[1]  2  3 NA NA  3  2  1  1

[[4]]
[1]  2  3  4 NA NA  2  1  1

[[5]]
[1]  2  3  4  4 NA NA  1  1

[[6]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3 NA NA  1

[[7]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3  2 NA NA

[[8]]
[1] NA  3  4  4  3  2  1 NA
```

Base R solutions are preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could either loop over the `list`, use the index to `replace` the values of 'y' to `NA`

```
lapply(l, \(x) replace(y, x, NA))
[[1]]
[1] NA NA  4  4  3  2  1  1

[[2]]
[1]  2 NA NA  4  3  2  1  1

[[3]]
[1]  2  3 NA NA  3  2  1  1

[[4]]
[1]  2  3  4 NA NA  2  1  1

[[5]]
[1]  2  3  4  4 NA NA  1  1

[[6]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3 NA NA  1

[[7]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3  2 NA NA

[[8]]
[1] NA  3  4  4  3  2  1 NA
```

---

Or another option is `is.na<-`

```
lapply(l, `is.na<-`, x = y)
[[1]]
[1] NA NA  4  4  3  2  1  1

[[2]]
[1]  2 NA NA  4  3  2  1  1

[[3]]
[1]  2  3 NA NA  3  2  1  1

[[4]]
[1]  2  3  4 NA NA  2  1  1

[[5]]
[1]  2  3  4  4 NA NA  1  1

[[6]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3 NA NA  1

[[7]]
[1]  2  3  4  4  3  2 NA NA

[[8]]
[1] NA  3  4  4  3  2  1 NA
```

Comment: That output are the elements of `y` that should become `NA`...

Comment: Could you please shortly explain `\(x)`.

Comment: @TarJae From `R 4.0`, the lambda function (`function (x)`) syntax notation can be concised with `\(x)` in `base R`.  i.e. the `x` here is each element of the `list`

Comment: Just to be clear, in the second case, there is no lambda function, i..e `x = y` with `x` is the argument name for the `is.na<-`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a base R solution with `lapply`.

```
lapply(l, \(x) {is.na(y) <- x; y})
#[[1]]
#[1] NA NA  4  4  3  2  1  1
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  2 NA NA  4  3  2  1  1
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  2  3 NA NA  3  2  1  1
#
#[[4]]
#[1]  2  3  4 NA NA  2  1  1
#
#[[5]]
#[1]  2  3  4  4 NA NA  1  1
#
#[[6]]
#[1]  2  3  4  4  3 NA NA  1
#
#[[7]]
#[1]  2  3  4  4  3  2 NA NA
#
#[[8]]
#[1] NA  3  4  4  3  2  1 NA
```